# How to sort digits in a number?

Tags: python, numbers

I'm trying to make an easy script in Python which takes a number and saves in a variable, sorting the digits in ascending and descending orders and saving both in separate variables. Implementing [Kaprekar's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6174).

It's probably a pretty noobish question. But I'm new to this and I couldn't find anything on Google that could help me. A site I found tried to explain a way using lists, but it didn't work out very well.

Comment: If this is a homework question (which it sounds like), you should be honest enough to tag it as such, and also explain what you've tried so far and where you failed.

Comment: Its not a homework project. I found an article on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6174 and I want to make a little script that calculates it automatically. I wish I had a school where I could learn Python or atleast programming more efficient, but Im stuck with Google (not that Im complaining) and whatever I can manage to squeeze out of the Python documentation.

If this was a homework project, I would tag it as one. But it isnt.

Comment: @DreamCodeR: Fair enough, please don't take offense.

Comment: Citing the wikipedia article would have helped to get the idea that we were sorting digits of numbers, not sorting lists of numbers.

Comment: @balpha: No offense taken :)
@hughdbrown: It really didnt occur to me since in my head it was always about digits and not lists, should have made it more clear. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sort the digits in ascending and descending orders:

```
ascending = "".join(sorted(str(number)))

descending = "".join(sorted(str(number), reverse=True))
```

Like this:

```
>>> number = 5896
>>> ascending = "".join(sorted(str(number)))
>>>
>>> descending = "".join(sorted(str(number), reverse=True))
>>> ascending
'5689'
>>> descending
'9865'
```

And if you need them to be numbers again (not just strings), call `int()` on them:

```
>>> int(ascending)
5689
>>> int(descending)
9865
```

---

2020-01-30

```
>>> def kaprekar(number):
...     diff = None
...     while diff != 0:
...         ascending = "".join(sorted(str(number)))
...         descending = "".join(sorted(str(number), reverse=True))
...         print(ascending, descending)
...         next_number = int(descending) - int(ascending)
...         diff = number - next_number
...         number = next_number
...
>>> kaprekar(2777)
2777 7772
4599 9954
3555 5553
1899 9981
0288 8820
2358 8532
1467 7641
```

Comment: `descending = ascending[::-1]`

Comment: incidentally, timsort is O(n) for cases like these

Comment: Doesn't work properly for this case because you need to add leading zeroes

Comment: Not sure what you mean @Mike. The code given in 2009 is perfectly good for implementing Kaprekar function, as shown in 2020-01-30 edit.

Comment: @hughdbrown for 1112 it will converge to 0 since you're not adding the leading zeroes. Adding .zfill(4) fixes that.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> x = [4,5,81,5,28958,28] # first list
>>> print sorted(x)
[4, 5, 5, 28, 81, 28958]
>>> x
[4, 5, 81, 5, 28958, 28]
>>> x.sort() # sort the list in place
>>> x
[4, 5, 5, 28, 81, 28958]
>>> x.append(1) # add to the list
>>> x
[4, 5, 5, 28, 81, 28958, 1]
>>> sorted(x)
[1, 4, 5, 5, 28, 81, 28958]
```

As many others have pointed out, you can sort a number forwards like:

```
>>> int(''.join(sorted(str(2314))))
1234
```

That's pretty much the most standard way.

Reverse a number?  Doesn't work well in a number with trailing zeros.

```
>>> y = int(''.join(sorted(str(2314))))
>>> y
1234
>>> int(str(y)[::-1])
4321
```

The `[::-1]` notation indicates that the iterable is to be traversed in reverse order.

Comment: +1. For descending order, use the 'reverse' keyword argument: x.sort(reversed=True), sorted(..., reverse=True)

Comment: The only problem is that I have one big number, f.ex.: 5896, which must be sorted as 5689 and 9865. Its just one large number.

Comment: You want to sort the digits of the numbers?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being too spesific =/

Comment: ascending = "".join(sorted(str(number)));
descending = "".join(sorted(str(number), reverse=True));

Answer (score 4):

As Mark Rushakoff already mentioned (but didn't solve) in his answer, `str(n)` doesn't handle numeric `n` with leading zeros, which you need for [Kaprekar's operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6174).  hughdbrown's answer similarly doesn't work with leading zeros.

One way to make sure you have a four-character string is to use the `zfill` string method.  For example:

```
>>> n = 2
>>> str(n)
'2'
>>> str(n).zfill(4)
'0002'
```

You should also be aware that in versions of Python prior to 3, a leading zero in a numeric literal indicated octal:

```
>>> str(0043)
'35'
>>> str(0378)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    str(0378)
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

In Python 3, `0043` is not a valid numeric literal at all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the python syntax, but thinking the generically, I would convert the input string into a character array, they do a sort on the character array, and lastly pipe it out.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an answer to the title question in Perl, with a bias toward sorting 4-digit numbers for the Kaprekar algorithm.  In the example, replace 'shift' with the number to sort.  It sorts digits in a 4-digit number with leading 0's ($asc is sorted in ascending order, $dec is descending), and outputs a number with leading 0's:

```
my $num = sprintf("%04d", shift);
my $asc = sprintf("%04d", join('', sort {$a <=> $b} split('', $num)));
my $dec = sprintf("%04d", join('', sort {$b <=> $a} split('', $num)));
```