# Kaprekar's constant (sorted(numbers)

Tags: python, list, sorting, random

Okay I've broken down step by step what the function needs to do.
create random number, sort ascending and descending(needs both), subtract, sort the new number ascending and descending and repeat this until the number you get from subtraction is 6174 (preferably I'd like it to loop a time or two after as it should stay at 6174 "which is why it's called Kaprekar's constant".

What I currently have is a random number between 1000,9999. I kept getting (TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable) so I created a list and appended the random number to the list. I'm having issue with sorting the number ascending/descending.

```py
import random
numbers = []
n = random.randint(1000,9999)
print(n)
numbers.append(n)
sorted(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

So I create a blank list, random number is generated and then printed, the number is then .append to the list and should sort and print the list.

The current output I get is
6988
[6988]

The expected output of what is written is
6988
[6889]

I attempted to use

```py
print(numbers.sort(reverse=True))
```

this gave "None"
I was expecting it to give [9886]

The only reason this is happening is that it wants to sort multiple items in the list opposed to sorting the numbers in the single item. I'm just not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: You only have one single number in a list, what you mean by sort ascending and descending? I guess this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301156/how-to-sort-digits-in-a-number

Comment: @ivvija the first link might be the answer; I believe the how to sort is where my edits are at now as my current output is 7201 [0, 1, 2, 7].Give me one moment to read that first link and update as necessary

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301156/how-to-sort-digits-in-a-number did resolve the issue. Thank you everyone; how do I close it out?

Comment: @navi I don't think you can close your own question, but if enough people vote to mark this question as a duplicate of the question linked, it will be closed and there will be a message with the link.

Comment: Note that Kaprekar's constant cannot be achieved unless the starting number contains at least 2 different digits. Therefore using a random selection may not be a good idea

Comment: @LancelotduLac That's something I definitely oversighted; I'll have to see what I can do to the randint to have it regenerate if it lands on a number like that. I appreciate the heads up

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is a list.sort method returns None.

```py
import random
numbers = []
n = random.randint(1000,9999)

numbers.append(n)

numbers.sort(reverse=True)
print(numbers)
```

Also `reverse=True` does not reverse the element but it reverses the list.

You can check this by this

```py
import random
numbers = []
n = random.randint(1000,9999)


numbers.append(n)
numbers.append(10)

print(sorted(numbers))
print(sorted(numbers,reverse=True))
```

If you want to reverse element then use this one

```py
import random
lst = []
num = random.randint(1000,9999)
print(num)
lst.append(num)

func = lambda e:int(str(e)[::-1]) # lambda function

lst = list(map(func,sorted(lst)))
print(lst)
```

NOTE:

1. 1000 after reversing become 1 'cause int('0001') is 1.
2. 4590 after reversing become 954 'cause int('0954') is 954.

Comment: @navi I hope you get some knowledge from my answer post.

Comment: lqbal just to confirm with the NOTE above if I changed. func = lambda e:int(str(e)[1::]) for a number like 4590 it would go to 9540.  So the first number generated will be sorted twice to get the lowest and highest arranged numbers IE (9540, 0459) those two numbers will then need to subtract for the new number to sort for again both the lowest and highest  so using (9540-0459)  the new number to sort would be 9081. The goal is to have it repeat until 6174. *if you try this should happen at iteration 7 no matter what starting (for digit number) you use*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite following you but I think you would like to have the individual digits of the randomly generated number as a list.

If so try doing:

```
my_str = str(n)
for my_char in my_str:
   numbers.append(int(my_char))
```

instead of:

```
numbers.append(n)
```

Comment: I switched to your suggestion removing lines 5-7 and added numbers.sort() and I'm now getting 7201
[0, 1, 2, 7]

Comment: Or just `numbers = sorted(str(n))`. No need for all this `.append` business.

Comment: @Stef Just to check the reason .append isn't needed is because the list makes the number a string?

Comment: @navi `str` can be used to get a string from a number. A string is not a list, but it has *a few* properties in common with a list. One of those properties is that you can apply `sorted` to it. And `sorted` returns a list.